# ERROR MOUNTING a single internal HDD used as EXTERNAL via USB PORT

Tags: usb, mount

This internal HDD used as external hard disk via USB PORT carried data without any OS in it..
It is currently in NTFS type format.

**Problem**
Once while I was browsing on this HDD1 (External one) it crashed or whatever... I don't know.

Then I needed that data...so I thought of using UBUNTU 14.01 to access that data.

But when I did so, all other HDDs are accessible but it shows error that is--
Ubuntu shows that HDD name as "DYNAMIC"

ERROR MESSAGE IS--

```
Unable to access "DYNAMIC"

 Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at 
/media/ubuntu/DYNAMIC: Command-line 'mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/ubuntu/DYNAMIC" exited with non-zero exit

status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i:ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error

NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or its a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk/f on windows. Then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device undet the /dev/mapper/directory, (e.g. dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount it with **-ro** (read-only) and if that also fails check with **dmesg | grep sd | less** for error messages regarding your drive.

```
mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,ro" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/ubuntu/DYNAMIC
```

In case of really severe issues, there is usually something like "sense key" in those lines along with an error message.

Comment: Then i need to know how to do that.... -ro ??

Comment: In the options ( -o). i edited the post above.